# Search in VS Code, but \s is not equal to [ \f\n\r\t\v]

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to replace extra blank after every line which matched like this

```regex
[\s]+\n
```

[image]

the problem is empty lines will also be matched

[image]

Base on my understanding, "\s" is equal to "[ \f\n\r\t\v]", so I changed the expression into

```regex
[ \f\r\t\v]+\n
```

to rule out "\n", but this time I got nothing...

[image]

Anybody knows why?

Comment: @PatrickArtner `^` is start of line, `$` is end of line

Comment: did you try `\s+$` ? There is no need for `[]` around `\s` and `$` is the "end of line" - if you replace that with `''` you should be fine. @rioV8 .. lacking morning coffee, thanks for correcting

Comment: you don't have the `.*` button selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Background**

First of all, Visual Studio Code regex does not work in the usual way sometimes as it was "tweaked" to work with a text editor.

Here, note that `\s` only matches line break chars (vertical whitespace) if there is `\n` or `\r` in the pattern. So, `[\s]+\n` matches across lines, it matches 1 or more **any** whitespace chars, and then stops at the last newline in this chunk of whitespaces.

So, if you need to match horizontal whitespace at the end of a line, I thought you could use a combination of `\s+` (one or more whitespace chars) and `$` (end of a line).

**However**, `\s+$` only matches whitespace at the end of a line if there are at least two occurrences of the whitespace chars.

**Solution**

```
\s*$
```

Demo screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

to find white space at ends of lines I would use

```
[ \t]+(?=\r?\n)
```

It will not catch the last line with white space if it has no `\n`. For that you need to use `$` that is not affected by `\n`

```
[ \t]+$
```